Two paintings come to life and are chased by a man
I'm trying to find the title of a movie that I watched when I was younger.
It's an old animated movie that I watched on a video cassette recording we had. I believe it was already old back then (around 1995) so it probably came out in the 1980s or even before that. Unfortunately I have no idea what country it was made in, I can only say that it wasn't a German movie.
Content I remember from the movie:

There was a man who owned two paintings, one of a woman (a princess maybe?) and one of a man. Both men were in love with the woman but the woman only loved the man in the painting.
The man had a ladder in his painting that enabled them to escape together one night. The owner of the paintings chased them afterwards.
At some point the man who owned the paintings got replaced by a copy of himself. I remember it being his mirror image that forced him to switch sides but maybe it was another painting considering that the other two people also came from paintings.
Near the end of the movie the building they were in collapsed.
 The last scene featured something emerging from the rubble. Whether it was any of the people mentioned before I don't know, but whatever it was then set off towards the horizon.

Does that sound familiar to anyone?
Edit:

The thing emerging from the rubble was a bird that had some significance in the story.


After remembering the bird I started another search and found what I was looking for:
It's The King and the Mockingbird, an animated French movie (Le Roi et l'oiseau) from 1980.

From the wiki page

In his secret apartment, the king dreams of the beautiful shepherdess whose painting he keeps on his wall, but the shepherdess is in love with the chimney sweep whose hated portrait is on the opposite wall. At night the paintings come to life and attempt to escape from the palace, but are pursued by a non-cross-eyed painting of the king that also has come to life, deposed the real king and has taken his place.

The man in the painting had a ladder because he's a chimney sweep, the woman in the painting isn't a princess but a shepherdess and as I assumed the king was replaced by a painting of himself, not his mirror image.

The bird and his sons take control of the robot and start destroying the castle.

Now the robot I didn't remember at all but that's the collapsed building I mentioned.

Sitting on the ruins of the castle the next morning, the robot sees one of the Bird's sons trapped in a cage. After freeing the bird, the robot smashes the cage, symbolizing the birds' freedom and the movie ends.

Again the part with the robot is missing from my memory but that is the last scene where the bird emerges from the rubble and flies away.
